# AngularJS Ng-grid - TabIndex not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, tabindex

I am using ng-grid to render my data. My cells have links in it which are defined using template.

See plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCcuBqd7RuZ0SHvz4BZp?p=preview)

When I am on input text box and when I click tab button, the focus should move to links in the grid, in this case "myLink", but it does not :(

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="text" />
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I edit the div class="ngViewport" in firebug console and just edit anything, say I modify tabindex="0" to "0" itself and save, the tabbing starts working....

Comment: have you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: I discarded the entire ng-grid and created my own table directive.

Comment: sadly, this is often the only option with 3rd party controls...